# Rails - One User multiple Addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :shipping_address_id; :billing_address_id
end
```

and an Address model

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :country_id, :city, :plz, :street, :streetnr, :first_name, :last_name
end
```

What I want to do via active record associations: Each user has a billing_address and a shipping_address. Can I create a relation so I can access these like user.billing_address?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add class name and foreign key in belongs_to association.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :shipping_address_id; :billing_address_id
    belongs_to :billing_address, class_name: :Address, foreign_key: :billing_address_id
    belongs_to :shipping_address, class_name: :Address, foreign_key: :shipping_address_id
end
```

Then you can access addresses like

```
user.billing_address
user.shipping_address
```

Comment: should belongs_to be has_one?

Comment: Foreign keys are in User model in this question. In order to use has_one in User model, foreign keys have to be in Address model.

Comment: user belongs to :address, weird.

Comment: Well, this worked perfectly for me. I even had something similar before but had the belongs_to association wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The method mentioned by @kengo should work but the more proper way would be

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :first_name, :last_name, :shipping_address_attributes; :billing_address_attributes
  has_one :billing_address, :class_name => 'Address'
  has_one :shipping_address, :class_name => 'Address'
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :billing_address
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shipping_address
end
```

This way you can have nested forms to accept values for your shipping and billing address. Moreover you will have your basic requirement fulfilled too.

Comment: How do you set up association keys in this case? Do we need to add columns in Address model?

Comment: I think kengo is right, the association is kinda missing here.